# How to interpolate string in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an angular web application, so I would like to use angular also for string interpolations. For example, I would like to make some replacements in `myTemplate`:

```
var myTemplate = "Make something awesome with a = '{{scope.a}}' and b = '{{scope.b}}'.";
var scope = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2
};
```

I know how to do this with underscore.js:

```
_.template(myTemplate)(scope);
```

I'm wondering if it is possible in angular?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use $interpolate service:

```
var myTemplate = "Make something awesome with a = '{{a}}' and b = '{{b}}'.";
var scope = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2
};

$interpolate(myTemplate)(scope); // "Make something awesome with a = '1' and b = '2'."
```

Only with above `scope` object structure, you should use `{{a}}` instead of `{{scope.a}}`.

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/aoaeWekhkLP5k7NR2RWB?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can make use of angular's [**`$interpolate`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interpolate) service

```
var myTemplate = "Make something awesome with a = '{{a}}' and b = '{{b}}'.";
var fn = $interpolate(myTemplate);

var scope = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2
};


// Make something awesome with a = '1' and b = '2'.
fn(scope);
```